# Black lines save as grey

Tags: layers, scanning, black, cc-2015

I am a very basic user, I scan pencil (comic) drawings as tiffs and use Photoshop cc 2015 to darken the lines and clean up a bit, and put text balloons and save again as tiffs. I use the 'levels' layer to blacken.

I have done this for a while (15-20 drawings) but now I have a page that shows nicely on screen but when I save as tiff (or bmp or anything) the black drawing lines that I see on screen are grey.

When I merge they also become grey. When I merge and add a new 'levels' layer it shows black nicely again but when I merge and/or save, they black becomes grey again. I suspect I changed a setting.

Before merging it looks like this:

[image: Before merging]

After merging or saving it looks like this:

[image: After merging]

Comment: Are you viewing at 100% when making adjustments? You should *always* because at *any* zoom level, but especially with reductions, there can be *preview* anti-aliasing taking place altering what you see.

Comment: Thank you. Good question. I work at 10-50%, and indeed at 100% there is actually no visible difference between the two above images. But playing with it and increasing the left 'level' from 178 as the image above as high as 253 makes no difference. It seems that the "levels" layer is active and shows on screen but is ignored when merging or saving.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I found the answer. I must have scanned the tiff file under a different format than greyscale. Perhaps B&W? I rescanned my drawing as I always do, and now the same layers work fine!
Cheers. GiB